# Как поместить значения всех ключей в один массив?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Есть объект с именами участников. Значение каждого участника URL. Подскажите, как наиболее быстро и просто пройтись циклом по объекту и добавить каждый `url` в один массив? Какую конструкцию для этого следует использовать ?

Чтоб получилась запись вида `["url" , "url" , "url" , "url" ]`

Вот объект :

```js
{
  "137": {
    "Саша": "url"
  },

  "122": {
    "Женя": "url"
  },
  "144": {
    "Лена": "url"
  },
  "145": {
    "Таня": "url"
  },

  "146": {
    "Игорь": "url"
  }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj = {
  "137": {
    "Саша": "url"
  },

  "122": {
    "Женя": "url"
  },
  "144": {
    "Лена": "url"
  },
  "145": {
    "Таня": "url"
  },

  "146": {
    "Игорь": "url"
  }
};

var urls = [];
for (var k in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
    urls.push(obj[k][Object.keys(obj[k])[0]]);
  }
}
console.log(urls); // ["url", "url", "url", "url", "url"]
```